# Visual C# make web request like python's

Tags: c#, python, http, httpwebrequest

i'm having a little piece of python code which makes a web request using the `urllib2` as you can se below

```
import json
import urllib2

urlRequest = urllib2.Request('<link>')
urlRequest.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
urlRequest.add_header('RegistrationToken', '<token>')

data = {
    'content': '<c>',
    'messagetype': 'RichText',
    'contenttype': 'text',
    'id': '<id>'
}

urllib2.urlopen(urlRequest, json.dumps(data))
```

As i was trying to do it in C# i came across the following problems

- how to i send the `data`
- how do i add the headers?

After googling for a while i managed to write this code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_input.Text);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers["RegistrationToken"] = rtoken_input.Text;
request.GetResponse();
```

I managed to deal with the headers part but the question on the `data` still remains. Also what is the best way to json encode something?

Anyone who knows what to do?

Comment: This was the first google item: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=VS.110).aspx

Comment: @gustavodidomenico didn't helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after serializing the POST data to a JSON payload there are few options.

1) System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json(v=vs.111).aspx)

2) using the JSON.NET library [Link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

As for your attempt on converting python to C# you are on the correct track.
Refer to [this link](http://solvedstack.com/questions/how-to-post-json-to-the-server)

Alternatively you could make use of the WebClient class [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)
Refer to [this link](http://solvedstack.com/questions/posting-json-to-url-via-webclient-in-c) as well

Pseudo code

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
client.Headers.Add("RegistrationToken", "<token>");
string response = client.UploadString("<link>", "<json string>");
```